# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Mon Aug 23 2021 19:00:04 GMT+0300)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I wanna show the time using const date inside tag . When I use

```
{new Date().getFullYear()}
```

instead

```
{date}
```

it's OK. Otherwise, I get an error message: "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Mon Aug 23 2021 19:06:50 ...). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Why is this happening? And how I can get date like "Mon Aug 23 2021 19:00:04" ?
Thanks alot for the answer.

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const date = new Date();

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <h1> {date} </h1>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: `date` is a date object and you can't render an object inside JSX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var date = new Date()

console.log(typeof date)

console.log(typeof date.getFullYear())
```

React doesn't accept Objects as its children, When you try to render as you mentioned above date variable is a date object, So react throws error and when you use `date.getFullYear()` it returns a string which is a valid react children. So it renders without throwing any error

For you to display date as mentioned in the question you can use `toString` method on date object, Refer below

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const date = new Date();

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <h1> {date.toString()} </h1>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I got. How about if I want to show the date like: "Mon Aug 23 2021 19:00:04"? What should I do with const date?

Comment: @SweetCaramel Please check  my updated answer

Comment: You can also take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date, on the left sidebar you have all methods you can use and what they return